# No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available in dev sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I'm newer to SF development, so if I left out any details, please let me know and I can update the question.

I'm trying to use a lightning aura component as a quick action.
I created a VERY basic component as a test and I'm still getting the **"Error: No Lightning Component Quick Actions are available for your organization."**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
  <b>This is a quick action </b>
</aura:component>
```

No matter what, I get the following error when trying to add the component as a new action for an object.  The same thing pops up if I'm trying to add a global action.

[image]

We have existing Lightning Component quick actions in the system. When I click "edit" on one of them, I get the following:
[image]

This appears to only be a problem in my Dev sandbox.  The QA/UAT sandboxes do not have this problem.  I have access to multiple Lightning Components that are set up as quick actions in those environments.  Same thing with the Production environment. I can use these Lightning Component quick actions there as well.

Comment: Can you check the https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DIjwQAG have the solution for similar kind of issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AnkaiahBandi - I have come across this post, but it did not really shed any light for me.  They talk about their Dev environment being recently updated from production and some managed package being installed that had a wonky aura component.  They say they THINK that was the problem but give no indications of how they determined that other than blindly uninstalling managed packages.
I checked the managed packages on QA (where this works) and dev and they match with the exception of Activity Components by Webider on QA and not in Dev.